# Kottwitz's vertical map

Tags: nt.number-theory, rt.representation-theory, reductive-groups

I'm looking at the map $w_H$ defined by Kottwitz in "Isocrystals with additional structure II" in section 7. It is a surjective group homomorphism defined for all reductive groups $H$ from $H$ to $X^{*}(Z(\hat{H})^{I})$ where $I$ is a Galois group and $\hat{G}$ denotes the dual of $G$.

To define this for arbitrary reductive groups and not merely ones with $H_{sc}$ simply connected  Kottwitz introduces a $z$-extension $H'$ of $H$ and a vertical arrow from $X^{*}(Z(\hat{H'})^{I})$ to $X^{*}(Z(\hat{H})^{I})$. But he doesn't define the map this arrow represents, and the only natural thing I can think of goes the other way.

Comment: This is probably way too late, but $H' \to H$ will induce a homomorphism $Z(\hat{H}) \to Z(\hat{H}')$ and then taking characters will reverse the direction, so what Kottwitz says is OK.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense: I must have forgotten to reverse somewhere in writing down the map